# SFTP (or similar) server automated setup for group spaces

Tags: sftp, automation, ftp, ftps

I need to build a dedicated machine which will be used to allow our clients to upload and download files in a secure manner.

Each client has multiple users, and I would rather not hand out generic client users which are used by multiple people. Each client should have access to their files only, and no others.

There is no use-case (yet) for multiple clients interacting with a single file or space.

Is there an existing solution to automating the creation and maintenance of these accounts, preferably with a view to integration with LDAP? Currently it looks like if we want to use SFTP with chrooted spaces they will need to be set up manually (or an automation hand-rolled).

If a solution exists for a different (but still secure) transfer method, such as FTPS, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at CrushFTP. It can run on a number of platforms and is very reasonably priced. Support is great and it is very feature rich. There is a free trial available and support is good even during trial.  Supports SFTP,FTPS and other protocols  I belive LDAP integration is supported.

Ypu can configure users so they can access the same files but have different permissions.

The system will send alerts based on a number of criteria like an upload or download. It has so many features you will likley need to test for some time to explore all options.

[CrushFTP site](http://www.crushftp.com)

Comment: That's really useful, thanks. It looks like it does exactly what we need. Either my Google-foo or their SEO must have been lacking.

Comment: I spent significant time looking for such a solution. Was very happy when I found CrushFTP.  Agree SEO or something is off but ...  It has worked very well for us.